# Symfony - ChoiceType Form - Array to string conversion error

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony

I'm trying to make a form with a choice type input on the field roles on my entity user.
However, Symfony reply me an error "Array to string conversion error"

My roles don't have to be an array because the are not multiple (role hierarchy in security.yaml).

Here is my Form Builder :

```
 $builder
        ->add('email')
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('password', PasswordType::Class)
        ->add('confirm_password', PasswordType::Class)
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => [
                'Utilisateur' => "ROLE_USER",
                'Valideur' => "ROLE_VALIDEUR",
                'Administrateur' => "ROLE_ADMIN",                    
            ],

        ])
```

And my User entity :

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Length(min="8", minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 carractères")
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="password", message="Vous n'avez pas tapé le même mot de passe")
 */
private $confirm_password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array")
 */
private $roles = array();

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Email()
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $email;



public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getConfirmPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->confirm_password;
}

public function setConfirmPassword(string $confirm_password): self
{
    $this->confirm_password = $confirm_password;

    return $this;
}

public function getRoles(): array
{
    return array_unique($this->roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

public function getPrenom(): ?string
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

public function setPrenom(?string $prenom): self
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

public function getNom(): ?string
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function setNom(?string $nom): self
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
} 

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function getSalt()
{
}
}
```

Could you explain me where are the problems in my user Entity (or somewhere else) please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem here is that Symfony trying to convert the value of the choice type to an array for user roles because the choice value is a string `'Utilisateur' => "ROLE_USER"`.

The only solution is to not define a specific entity for the form and after apply values to the user entity.

1. First, create the user type when the form will be :

```php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // The builder doesn't change
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('password', PasswordType::Class)
            ->add('confirm_password', PasswordType::Class)
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Utilisateur' => 'ROLE_USER',
                    'Validateur' => 'ROLE_VALIDATEUR',
                    'Administrateur' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([]);
    }
}
```

2. After, create your controller and create the form :

```php
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        // Create the form
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);

        // Render the Twig file and pass the form as a view
        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

3. Then, you have to process the form and assign all properties to your entity like this :

```php
public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);

    // Processing the form from the request
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Check if form is submitted
    if($form->isSubmitted()) {

        // Fetch data from the form
        $data = $form->getData();

        // Create user from data
        $user = (new User)
            ->setEmail($data['email'])
            ->setPrenom($data['prenom'])
            ->setNom($data['nom'])
            ->setPassword($data['password'])
            ->setConfirmPassword($data['confirm_password'])
            // Here, we convert the string to an array
            ->setRoles([$data['roles']]);

        // Add the user to the database
        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

4. There is another problem with the code above: violations are not triggering and an error is throwing when there are conflicts between two entities (during `$manager->flush()`). The following code is the correction (we can use the [validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) to check if an entity is valid):

```php
// Request validator as injection dependency
public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager, ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class);

    // Set default values for validation variables
    $violations = null;
    $conflict = false;

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $user = (new User)
            ->setEmail($data['email'])
            ->setPrenom($data['prenom'])
            ->setNom($data['nom'])
            ->setPassword($data['password'])
            ->setConfirmPassword($data['confirm_password'])
            // Here, we convert the string to an array
            ->setRoles([$data['roles']]);

        // Get violations from the user entity with the 'validate' function
        $violations = $validator->validate($user);

        // Check if there are no violations. If it is, the user is valid
        if($violations->count() === 0) {
            $manager->persist($user);

            // Catch a unique constraint violation exception during flushing
            try {
                $manager->flush();
            } catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
                $conflict = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),

        // Pass violations and conflict
        'violations' => $violations,
        'conflict' => $conflict
    ]);
}
```

**I hope that I help you!**

*If you want create a field where we can select multiple roles, [this link](https://nouvelle-techno.fr/actualites/2020/01/10/live-coding-gerer-les-roles-utilisateur-avec-symfony-4) may help you (the website is French).*

Comment: This solution remove the error message indeed but, how "$form->isValid()" is suppose to check for the validity of the data if it doesn't know wich entity is it ?
I've tried to submited a form with some error and the "$form->isValid()" respond "true I'm happy with these incorrect data"

Comment: Yes, you have right @Benjamin! `$form->isValid()` is unnecessary. But you can check if the entity is valid, after the submitting, by using [the validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service). I will correct the answer.

Comment: Ok YaFou for your proposition (after you will correct it). Is there any sexiest way to do this ? For example by modifiying the geter and seter of the Entity to manage string instead of an array ? (To avoid the array to string conversion error).

Comment: I will work on your suggestion @Benjamin. I have tested a little time but without any success. I think the problem doesn't come from there.

Comment: I've tried to implement this solution but it doesn't work properly because we are trying to make the same thing that the "isValid' method but without it. For example if the form is submited with a field with nothing inside, the set method will say : "I'm waiting for a string and you give me null".
What I enderstand is that the "isValid" method and other around the form will work only with "$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user)". But if I do that, the Roles have to be string in database, not an array because of the array to string conversion. Is there any way to do that this way ?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add this in your UserType

```
$builder->get('roles')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($rolesArray) {
                // transform the array to a string
                return count($rolesArray)? $rolesArray[0]: null;
            },
            function ($rolesString) {
                // transform the string back to an array
                return [$rolesString];
            }
        ));
```

Answer (score -1):

I've tried something different to resolve the problem but still not completly ok.

To avoid the array to string conversion I've change my User entity like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $roles;

public function getRoles(): array
{
    return array($this->roles);
}

public function setRoles(?string $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}
```

The roles are string but I have to convert it to an array in the getRoles method because the UserAuthenticationProvider need it.

There is nothing special in my controller, just the form creation with the entity.

```
/**
 * @Route("/users/nouveau", name="users_nouveau")
 */
public function nouveau()
{ 
    $newUser = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $newUser);

    return $this->json([], 200);
}
```

Here is my UserType Form :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email')
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('password', PasswordType::Class)
        ->add('confirm_password', PasswordType::Class)
        ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => [
                'Utilisateur' => "ROLE_USER",
                'Valideur' => "ROLE_VALIDEUR",
                'Administrateur' => "ROLE_ADMIN",                    
            ],

        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
    ]);
}

}
```

I don't understand why there is still an array to string conversion error.